# Two arrays into one Dictinary C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I would like to create a

`Dictionary<string, int[]> dict`

out of two arrays(different length):

```
string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D", "C","E" };
string[] values = { green, blue, yellow};
```

The results:

```
["A"] = {green} 
["B"] = {blue}
["D"] = {yellow}
["C"] = {green}
["E"] = {blue}
```

Comment: i'm not sure how your data is mapped exactly... what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: Is that `["A"] , {green} ` a `<string, int[]>` pair?

Comment: Looks like you are not really looking for a dictionary, but something reversed: map multiple entries to a single object

Comment: Your example result can **not** be stored in a `Dictionary<string, int[]>`. Either your example result is wrong, or you need to correct to desired result type to what it should be. Also, `string[] values = { green, blue, yellow }` is *only* correct syntax if `green` and `blue` and `yellow` have been pre-defined as `string` constants or `string` variables. Sorry, but details are important.

Answer (score 4):

Your dictionary in that case would be `Dictionary<string,string>`.
From your sample, it looks like you want the modulus (%) operator for the values array to deal with the array length differences.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++) { 
   var j = i % values.Length; 
   dict[keys[i]] = values[j];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like he wants a modulo, as A and C are both green

Comment: @BartvanderDrift This code works as the user requested, except he needs to first get only unique keys: `keys = keys.Distinct().ToArray();` (otherwise the code still works, but with different values since the duplicate keys are re-assigned new values as the array is processed).

Answer (score 2):

You can try a simple *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...
```

If `key` contains **unique** items only:

```
  // here all keys are unique
  string[] keys = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
  string[] values = { "green", "blue", "yellow" };

  Dictionary<string, string> result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, keys.Length)
    .ToDictionary(i => keys[i], i => values[i % values.Length]);
```

If **not** and we should skip `key` when it appears again

```
  // Note, that "A" key repeats twice
  string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D", "C", "E" };
  string[] values = { "green", "blue", "yellow" };

  Dictionary<string, string> result = keys
    .Distinct()
    .Select((key, i) => new {
      key,
      value = values[i % values.Length]
    })
    .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
[A, green]
[B, blue]
[D, yellow]
[C, green]
[E, blue]
```